# Не работает DecisionTreeClassifier (pyspark.ml, Spark 2.4.0)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

В моей таблице около 50 млн. записей, около 400 столбцов. У меня не получается использовать DecisionTreeClassifier (pyspark.ml, Spark 2.4.0) - всё зависает, хотя для маленьких выборок всё работает. Модель я делал примерно как здесь: https://habr.com/ru/post/522296/.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что можно сделать.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Рекомендую как минимум проапгердиться до 3.2...

Comment: Проапгрейдить я не имею возможности (((